# Match statement does not catch a Logos lexer token

Tags: parsing, rust, switch-statement, pattern-matching

I'm having trouble understanding why one branch of the `match` statement is not traversed when the conditions are met.

This is the minimum reproducible code that I have been able to write, followed by the panic, the trace and Cargo.toml. The problem in question is in the `Ok(Token::CloseParen)` branch the 'match' statement of the function `read_list()`. Never enters into that branch when parsing `"(1 2 3)"`.

```rust
use std::vec::Vec;
use core::iter::Peekable;

use logos::{Logos, Lexer};

#[derive(Debug)]
pub enum MalType {
    Integer(i64),
    List(Vec<MalType>)
}

#[derive(Logos, Debug, PartialEq, Clone)]
#[logos(skip r"[\s,]*")] 
enum Token {
    #[token("(")]
    OpenParen,

    #[token(")")]
    CloseParen,
    
    #[regex(r#"-?\d+"#, |lex| lex.slice().parse().ok(),priority=2)]
    Integer(i64),
}

fn main() -> () {
    let mut lexer = Token::lexer("(1 2 3)").peekable();
    println!("created() : {:?}",lexer);

    read_from(&mut lexer);
    ()
}

fn read_from(lexer: &mut Peekable<Lexer<Token>>) -> MalType {
    match lexer.peek() {
        Some(Ok(Token::OpenParen)) => {
            read_list(lexer)},
        Some(Ok(Token::Integer(i))) => MalType::Integer(*i),
        Some(Ok(_)) => panic!("Reader Error: read_atom should not arrive here- {:?}",lexer.peek().unwrap() ),
        _ => panic!("Yeay, it should not get here"),

    }
}

fn read_list(lexer: &mut Peekable<Lexer<Token>>) -> MalType {
    let mut list: Vec<MalType> = Vec::new();

    while let Some(token) = lexer.next() {
        println!("token : {:?}",lexer.peek());
        match token {
            Ok(Token::CloseParen) => {return MalType::List(list)},
            Ok(_) => list.push(read_from(lexer)),
            Err(_) => panic!("ReadError: read_list")
        }
        println!("list : {:?}", &list);
    }
    return MalType::List(list);
}
```

the result with backtraces (both with `println!` and the proper one) tells me that the lexer does the lexing correctly, but when the reader reaches the final token (`CloseParen`) in `read_list()` instead of taking the correct branch, it jumps to the default for `Ok(_)` where it goes to `read_from()` where goes to it should go, and matches with `Ok(_)`, paniking.

```bash
$ RUST_BACKTRACE=1 cargo run
    Finished dev [unoptimized + debuginfo] target(s) in 0.01s
     Running `target/debug/mal`
created() : Peekable { iter: {"source": "(1 2 3)", "extras": ()}, peeked: None }
token : Some(Ok(Integer(1)))
list : [Integer(1)]
token : Some(Ok(Integer(2)))
list : [Integer(1), Integer(2)]
token : Some(Ok(Integer(3)))
list : [Integer(1), Integer(2), Integer(3)]
token : Some(Ok(CloseParen))
thread 'main' panicked at 'Reader Error: read_atom should not arrive here- Ok(CloseParen)', src/main.rs:38:24
stack backtrace:
   0: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/9eb3afe9ebe9c7d2b84b71002d44f4a0edac95e0/library/std/src/panicking.rs:575:5
   1: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/9eb3afe9ebe9c7d2b84b71002d44f4a0edac95e0/library/core/src/panicking.rs:64:14
   2: imperium_alea::read_from
             at ./src/main.rs:38:24
   3: imperium_alea::read_list
             at ./src/main.rs:54:32
   4: imperium_alea::read_from
             at ./src/main.rs:36:13
   5: imperium_alea::main
             at ./src/main.rs:29:5
   6: core::ops::function::FnOnce::call_once
             at /rustc/9eb3afe9ebe9c7d2b84b71002d44f4a0edac95e0/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:250:5
note: Some details are omitted, run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=full` for a verbose backtrace.
```

The build was done with `cargo 1.68.2 (6feb7c9cf 2023-03-26)`, and the Cargo.toml file is

```ini
[package]
name = "mal"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

[dependencies]
logos = "0.13.0"
```

---

#### Aditional Info

For context, I'm trying to implement the [mal project](https://github.com/kanaka/mal/blob/master/process/guide.md#step-1-read-and-print), but with some changes as I wanted to understand the logos crate. I found this problem I and haven't been able to understand why it happens.

Answer (score 0):

```rust
    while let Some(token) = lexer.next() {
        println!("token : {:?}",lexer.peek());
        match token {
            Ok(Token::CloseParen) => {return MalType::List(list)},
            Ok(_) => list.push(read_from(lexer)),
```

When you get here and `token` is the last integer before a closing paren, then `lexer.peek()` will be that very closing paren, because `next()` has advanced the lexer. So `read_from(lexer)` does indeed see a lexer whose next token is the closing paren.

I think a viable fix would be changing `read_from` to take the current token as an argument in addition to the lexer, and then matching on that instead of `lexer.next()`. (And you know the token exists, so you can get rid of the needless Option matches.)

Answer (score 0):

When your parser reaches the `3`, `read_list` consumes it from the iterator, then sees it's not a `CloseParen` and calls `read_from`. `read_from` peeks the `CloseParen` and panics.

My advice is to not use `Peekable`. If you are writing recursive code, use the call stack to encode state. If you're writing iterative code, have an explicit state struct, or hold the state in the return type.

Here's a recursive version.

```rs
fn main() {
    let mut lexer = Token::lexer("(1 2 3)");
    println!("created() : {:?}", lexer);

    read(&mut lexer);
}

fn read(lexer: &mut Lexer<Token>) -> MalType {
    read_value(lexer).expect("unmatched close paren")
}

fn read_value(lexer: &mut Lexer<Token>) -> Option<MalType> {
    let token = lexer.next().expect("unexpected end");
    let token = token.expect("lexer error");
    let mal = match token {
        Token::OpenParen => MalType::List(read_list(lexer)),
        Token::CloseParen => return None,
        Token::Integer(i) => MalType::Integer(i),
    };
    Some(mal)
}

fn read_list(lexer: &mut Lexer<Token>) -> Vec<MalType> {
    std::iter::from_fn(|| read_value(lexer)).collect()
}
```

Here, list depth is represented by the number of calls to `read_list`. When an `OpenParen` is encountered, a new `read_list` is called, and when `CloseParen` is encountered, the last `read_list` is returned (or an error occurs).